# STM32 Debug Error: Target No Device Found on CubeIDE and Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, stm32, nucleo

Last year I used CubeIDE to develop simple firmwares of STM32.
After that I moved to Ubuntu from Windows, and recently I installed the new release of Ubuntu 21.04.

Today I purchased a new STM32L476RG Nucleo board.
So I installed CubeIDE 1.6.1 in my Ubuntu 21.04 and wrote a simple LED blink program.
I clicked F11 button for debugging, but there was an error, no ST-Link found.
Oh, I forgot to connect STM32 Nucleo to my USB port.
I connected it to my computer and run debugging again.
Now compiling, building successes but stoped at the final stage with this error message:

```
Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

And then an error message box popped up.

[image]

As I have not much experience in STM32 development and CubeIDE usage, I searched on Google and found several similar answers.
But none of them matched to my case.

I had no error when I was using CubeIDE on Windows last year with STM32F103 Nucleo board.
I'm not sure if it's related with my Ubuntu + CubeIDE configuration or related with my new L476RG Nucleo board.

If I can solve this issue in short, it would be great.
Thanks.

### Edit: Jumper settings

[image]

Comment: This happens when the ST-LINK is detected but the target uC is not. Are both ST-LINK jumpers in place?

Comment: Yes, both jumpers are there. I'll add the board picture on the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the picture you attached it seems you are missing one jumper. JP5 should be in U5V position if you want to power the STM part of the board from USB

Answer (score 1):

Hello referring to my case I found the solution yesterday, many are going through the same problem as me.

What I did was just use the following pins from the SWD connector.

I used pin 2 - SWCLK, pin 3 - GND, and pin 4 - SWDIO

Pin 1 of the SWD connector is a fake 3v3, so I used pin 4 of the CN6 connector that provides 3v3.

Comment: are you using l476rg? Can you tell me which pins are those?

Answer (score 0):

For the people using STM32G474RE or similar: By only changing jumper J5 from 5V_VIN to 5V_STLK, I was able to debug right away. (Once jumper J5 was in the right Spot 5V PWR LED was lit up).